# Veins 802.11p CSMA/CA and retransmission

Tags: omnet++, veins

Vehicles communicate using 802.11p on Veins 5.1, OmNET 5.6.2, sumo 1.8.0 environment.

My questions

1. Do I have to implement retransmission process(like CSMA/CA) when collision is occurred?
   or, is retransmission process(like CSMA/CA) already implemented in library or such class?
2. I want to use RTS/CTS option, do I have to implement it too?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question: the 802.11p modules that are included in Veins 5.1 trigger automatic retransmissions (following the 802.11 specification) for lost unicast messages if [the MAC layer `useAcks` parameter](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.1/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.ned#L68) is set to `true` (which is not the default). RTS/CTS is not implemented, so if you want to use **only** modules from Veins you would need to implement this yourself.

More generally, though, your research sounds like it might be better served if you would combine Veins with [The INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org/) (via [veins_inet](https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#veins_inet)); this would allow you to use [the more general 802.11 simulation model](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/users-guide/ch-80211.html) included in The INET Framework. It includes features like block-ACKs, RTS/CTS, fragmentation and reassembly, infrastructure mode, automatic rate selection, and many more.